# Configuring an F5 BIG-IP configuration on amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-server, f5-big-ip

I am a newbie to f5 BIG-IP. I want to configure an f5 BIG-IP instance to load balance 2 apache webservers under it.

I am following the documentation in following link. But not clear how to route traffic from f5 instance to Web servers under it.

https://support.f5.com/content/kb/en-us/products/big-iq-cloud/manuals/product/bigiq-and-amazon-ec2-setup-4-3-0/_jcr_content/pdfAttach/download/file.res/BIG-IQ_Systems_and_Amazon_EC2__Setup.pdf

If anyone has a documentation regarding this please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used F5 LTMs with Amazon, but I don't see why it should be different than onprem stuff. Create a pool with both servers and add it to your VIP. Use Source NAT if the servers are not behind the F5 (e.g. the F5 is working in one-arm mode or "router on a stick").

Answer (score 0):

Information on AWS deployment on F5's DevCentral [can be found in this article](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/deploying-f5-big-ip-in-aws-for-developers).